# ffmpeg with minimum bandwidth with watchable video quality

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, nginx

I want ffmpeg and my video stream to use minimum bandwidth with average video quality. As I'm new to the video streaming, I'm not sure what all configurations I should add or change in my ffmpeg command. I'm using following command as of now:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://xxxxx:xxxx123@xxxx.xxxx.net:9007/0/video0 -preset ultrafast -analyzeduration 500000 -probesize 500000 -fflags nobuffer -s 640x360 -r 5 -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency -an -f flv rtmp://xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/myapp3/livestream
```

If it helps, I'm using following components for live streaming:

```
1. Jwplayer
2. nginx-rtmp module (https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)
```

To get desired result, suggestions for changes in above components would be great.

Comment: So what's the current status? Does your command work? What quality or average bitrate does it produce? Do you need to reduce the bitrate? Or increase the quality?

Comment: yup! the command is working and using aws micro instance I'm able to stream video from one camera properly. As I start video streaming from another camera, the video starts to stutter. So I was wondering if we could use the minimum bandwidth for each camera, we could support more cameras.

Comment: How do you mean, you're streaming from another camera? As soon as you request two streams from the server, neither of the streams can be sent without stuttering? Maybe you could explain more about your setup.

Comment: Let's say I've two ffmpeg command in my nginx conf file which grabs video from cam1 and cam2 and streams video on livestream1 and livestream2 respectively. One command at a time works fine, but when I execute both ffpmeg at the same time, both videos start to stutter. So if I could minimize/improve bandwidth utilization for each ffmpeg maintaining avg video quality, streaming might go better.

Comment: @pkumar: if it's a bandwidth issue using a preset other than ultrafast might get you some more compression. But if it's a processing power issue this will just make things worse.